# magento 2 robots.txt file is not creating in root directory after enabling settings

Tags: magento2, robots.txt

Recently we have deployed the website to live and after when SEO ask to put the `robots.txt` file in root directory for search engine crawl.
We have checked setting in `Content > Design > Configuration` and edit the design and found the option search engine robots and already set but why `Magento 2` is not creating robots.txt file?

Is there any specific settings to allow this or do we need to put the file manually.

Please let me know if any one have idea for this section.

[image]

Comment: i think permission issue so you have First create robots.txt in root folder , give permission 777 and then check it

Comment: Ok,I have created file and give the 777 permissions.Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @akgola Hi, i tried give 777 permisions for robots.txt but it didn not update the file. did it work for you?

Comment: @KrisWen,I have only created robot.txt manually as per SEO suggestion and gave 777 permission and its working fine.

Comment: @akgola Thank you. Didn't work for me yesterday. I'll give it a try again.

Comment: I created it, gave permission but from backend, its not getting updated. Whats the issue. Anyone have any suggestion ?